# tokenize module

Tags: python, tokenize

Please help

There are many tokens in module tokenize like STRING,BACKQUOTE,AMPEREQUAL etc.

```
>>> import cStringIO
>>> import tokenize
>>> source = "{'test':'123','hehe':['hooray',0x10]}"
>>> src = cStringIO.StringIO(source).readline
>>> src = tokenize.generate_tokens(src)
>>> src
<generator object at 0x00BFBEE0>
>>> src.next()
(51, '{', (1, 0), (1, 1), "{'test':'123','hehe':['hooray',0x10]}")
>>> token = src.next()
>>> token
(3, "'test'", (1, 1), (1, 7), "{'test':'123','hehe':['hooray',0x10]}")
>>> token[0]
3
>>> tokenize.STRING
3
>>> tokenize.AMPER
19
>>> tokenize.AMPEREQUAL
42
>>> tokenize.AT
50
>>> tokenize.BACKQUOTE
25
```

This is what i experimented.But i was not able to find what they mean ?

From where i will understand this.I need an immediate solution.

Comment: "I need an immediate solution." huh?

Comment: "my class starts in ten minutes"

Answer (score 4):

The various AMPER, BACKQUOTE etc values correspond to the token number of the appropriate symbol for python tokens / operators.  ie AMPER = & (ampersand), AMPEREQUAL = "&=".

However, you don't actually have to care about these.  They're used by the internal C tokeniser, but the python wrapper simplifies the output, translating all operator symbols to the `OP` token.  You can translate the symbolic token ids (the first value in each token tuple) to the symbolic name using the token module's tok_name dictionary.  For example:

```
>>> import tokenize, token
>>> s = "{'test':'123','hehe':['hooray',0x10]}"
>>> for t in tokenize.generate_tokens(iter([s]).next):
        print token.tok_name[t[0]],

OP STRING OP STRING OP STRING OP OP STRING OP NUMBER OP OP ENDMARKER
```

As a quick debug statement to describe the tokens a bit better, you could also use tokenize.printtoken.  This is undocumented, and looks like it isn't present in python3, so don't rely on it for production code, but as a quick peek at what the tokens mean, you may find it useful:

```
>>> for t in tokenize.generate_tokens(iter([s]).next):
        tokenize.printtoken(*t)

1,0-1,1:        OP      '{'
1,1-1,7:        STRING  "'test'"
1,7-1,8:        OP      ':'
1,8-1,13:       STRING  "'123'"
1,13-1,14:      OP      ','
1,14-1,20:      STRING  "'hehe'"
1,20-1,21:      OP      ':'
1,21-1,22:      OP      '['
1,22-1,30:      STRING  "'hooray'"
1,30-1,31:      OP      ','
1,31-1,35:      NUMBER  '0x10'
1,35-1,36:      OP      ']'
1,36-1,37:      OP      '}'
2,0-2,0:        ENDMARKER       ''
```

The various values in the tuple you get back for each token are, in order:

1. token Id (corresponds to the type, eg STRING, OP, NAME etc)
2. The string - the actual token text for this token, eg "&" or "'a string'"
3. The start (line, column) in your input
4. The end (line, column) in your input
5. The full text of the line the token is on.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to read python's code [tokenizer.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Parser/tokenizer.c?revision=65543&view=markup) to understand the detail.
Just search the keyword you want to know. Should be not hard.

Answer (score 2):

Python's lexical analysis (including tokens) is documented at http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html .  As http://docs.python.org/library/token.html#module-token says, "Refer to the file Grammar/Grammar in the Python distribution for the definitions of the names in the context of the language grammar.".